# Angular - component page

Tags: angular, typescript

Hey I have a component and want to display it on a new page. However currently that's not working. It is just a brief flash of the component and then it disappears and no new page gets displayed. Can someone held me here?

That's my app.component.html:

```
<body class="bg-light">
<div class="content"> 
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-text">
       <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active">Profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <app-post></app-post>
      <app-timeline></app-timeline>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

That is my app.modules.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';   
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {NgSelectModule} from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import {ProfileComponent} from './profile/profile.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProfileComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),

  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppModule { }
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**UPDATE**

I fixed it however the app-post should not be display when I opened the profile page + the profile should be above the app-timline content. How can I do that?

this is the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/github/mastalier1997/PRDKE

Comment: you want to open in new tab?

Comment: remove slash from your routerLink

Comment: based on your description, if you are seeing the component show up then go away, that would suggest the router is correctly loading teh component in the router outlet, however something else is then replacing it. have you added console messages in the ProfileComponent ngOnInit to confirm it is being loaded. additionally you can subscribe to router changes in your app component to see if anything else is triggering changes in the router

Comment: nope in the same tab but it should only display the profile component

Comment: when I remove the slash it does not work

Comment: @Edward I did it and it logs the message, but the html does not get called

Comment: something outside of what you pasted must be in playing  part here. can you reproduce this in stackblitz so that people can look at the code and provide assistance?

Comment: I added a link and I fixed the problem, but have now a new one and updated the question therefore